# Netbeans Start Java Command Line Program then Auto-Attach for Remote Debugging

Tags: java, netbeans-7, remote-debugging

I'm enrolled in [Sedgewick's Algorithms](https://class.coursera.org/algs4partI-003/class/index) class through Coursera and am using Netbeans 7.3.1. In order to go through the lessons, work on exercises, and submit to the autograder, I have to be able to execute programs on the command line with IO redirection:

```
java MyProg < testdata.txt
```

I've tried adding `< testdata.txt` (with and without quotes) in the Project->Properties->Run arguments field, but this doesn't work because the redirection occurs at shell level and Netbeans doesn't pass that through.

I've come up with the solution to start MyProg for remote debugging. I use Netbeans for editing/building/compiling, then through a terminal window, I change to the project/build/classes directory then start up a JVM for debugging like this:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y, \ 
suspend=y UF < ../../tinyUF.txt
```

It's not a bad approach per se, all the Netbeans debugging features work just fine. What I'd like to do when I need to debug in this fashion is for Netbeans to execute MyProg for debugging, then automatically Attach-Debugger to that JVM instance. Shut things down at the end. It would be great if this approach would work for any Project I'm working on that requires remote debugging.

I'm not that new to Netbeans but I am at customizing it. I don't know where to start to configure this functionality, or even if it's possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but it you just need the debugger to be started right at the beginning, then you should use the listen mode? This way the JVM won't execute the code until you start the debugger.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj - I'd like to do this automatically. When I need to start a debug session, Netbeans starts MyProg for remote debugging, then Netbeans attaches to the JVM over address 8000.